# Jquery fails in chrome extension if a page or website have already a version of jquery. I want Jquery Selector script

Tags: javascript

i want jquery selector script. but i don't want to use jquery library.

i am building a chrome extension. when i use **jquery** in extension so when it called in a page or website which is using already jquery then it fails. Don't tell me for jquery.conflict().

i want a **library or script** which performs like:

```
$("#some").val()
$("some").val()
$(".some").val()
```

Atleast all possible functions, or minimum setAttributeValue()
I think you got it what i want...

Comment: This is what jquery uses - http://sizzlejs.com/

Comment: i know about sizzlejs. so any next opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the native `.querySelector()` or `.querySelectorAll()` methods to select the elements, then use the native `.value` property or `getAttribute()` method to retrieve what you need. Loading a library for this is like cracking a nut with a sledgehammer.